# CSS cursor:pointer in mac Safari doesn't work

Tags: css, cross-browser, mouse-cursor, safari

I have placed cursor:pointer on a td but in Safari (on a mac) it only displays the default mouse cursor instead of changing to the little hand pointer which it does in every other browser.

Is anyone aware if there is a fix for this or is it unavoidable?

Update: The code is something like this:

HTML

```
<td class="someClass"><span>text here</span></td>
```

CSS

```
td.someClass { cursor:pointer; }
```

Comment: usually this cursor works in Safari, pls give us a bit code.

Comment: code and or link please?.. im here on a mac with safari and can test it easily.. in my case its working so come up with details

Comment: sorry i can't add a link - I have to maintain anonyimity of the company. Another way of phrasing it - does anyone know of rendering differences between safari on a Mac and safari on a PC (same browser version). If not - i shall delete / answer my own question

Comment: @richardstelmach Please edit your question to include snippets of the relevant HTML and CSS. You will get both more answers and answers of a higher quality with code samples.

Comment: @dgvid html: '<td class="someClass"><span>text here</span></td>'. CSS: 'td.someClass{cursor:pointer;}'

Answer (score 10):

I came upon this question just now because I was finding safari was refusing to show the hand mouse pointer on a website I was developing. I actually tried testing default link behaviour in absence of any css, and still had a problem.

I found **restarting safari** fixed it. Come to think of it, just opening the same site in a different window might have fixed it.

These are things to try if you're stuck on a mouse pointer problem, because there's some quirk/bug/inconsistent state safari can get into.  In my case I imagine it may have been caused by playing around with debugging developer tools.

Comment: Restarting Safari did it for me too. I suspect it has to do with the cache. (Note: Same CSS was running like a charm on Chrome & FFX.)

Comment: I had the same issue. Restarting Safari fixed the temporary bug.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that it may have likely been down to the software the user was using to record their screen as I noticed it when watching a usability testing video - the user was using Safari on a mac. The software may have replaced the cursor as a means of tracking/recording its movement. I have since tested it on a mac, using Safari and it works. Using:
'td.someClass{cursor:pointer;}'

Answer (score 0):

Open the page in another tab to fix it.**You don't need to restart Safari.**

Answer (score 0):

Using `td.someClass:hover {cursor: pointer;}` instead of just `td.someClass {cursor: pointer;}` worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

In the past I remember using:

```
cursor:hand;
```

...for Safari.

Not sure if it's necessary any more, or if I just stopped using it.

Comment: There we go, I knew it was for some browser, wasn't sure which one. Such is life. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: I found it worked fine in Safari on the PC but I actually noticed it whilst watching a usability video (and the user was using safari on a mac), someone suggested that this was maybe caused by the software or website they were using to record the user's actions on the screen. Is anyone aware of any rendering differences between Safari on a Mac to on a PC?